# Jenkins dynamic use of token

Tags: authentication, jenkins, token, dvcs

When I use a hook to trigger a build from a DVCS like Bitbucket, I have to add a Jenkins API token to authenticate that the triggered user has the right to build this job.
But if I want to use the user token, specific to the user who checked in, I want Jenkins to look up if the token belongs to a permitted user and run the job on his behalf.
Any idea if there is a plug-in that makes the used token dynamic in Jenkins?